# Excel - Format value (mask)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I'd like to format a cell value this way:

1234,980 -> 1.234,980

12237119867,761 -> 12.237.119.867,761

How to prepare a common mask, that will set dots as thousand separators and a comma for decimals. The mask should work for any provided value.

Answer (score 8):

Define the first segment to the left of the decimal dot. It will be automatically duplicated as needed.
Number of octothorpes after the dot sets the maximum number of decimal places after the dot, only required number of the will be used.

Something like:

```
#.###,0##
```

(I'm assuming that would be valid for your current locale).

As suggested by the [phoog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385844/phoog)'s comment, locale-independent format would be:

```
#,###.0##
```

(use that to set format using `Cell.NumberFormat = "#,###.0##"`)

---

As for some VBA code, you may have an enhanced version of the `Format` function that accepts two locales, one which is the format string is in, and another one to use for formatting result.

Place the following in a separate module:

```vb
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VarTokenizeFormatString Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal pstrFormat As LongPtr, ByRef rgbTok As Any, ByVal cbTok As Long, ByVal iFirstDay As VbDayOfWeek, ByVal iFirstWeek As VbFirstWeekOfYear, ByVal lcid As Long, ByRef pcbActual As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VarFormatFromTokens Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByRef pvarIn As Variant, ByVal pstrFormat As LongPtr, ByRef pbTokCur As Any, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef pbstrOut As LongPtr, ByVal lcid As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#Else
Private Declare Function VarTokenizeFormatString Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal pstrFormat As Long, ByRef rgbTok As Any, ByVal cbTok As Long, ByVal iFirstDay As VbDayOfWeek, ByVal iFirstWeek As VbFirstWeekOfYear, ByVal lcid As Long, ByRef pcbActual As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function VarFormatFromTokens Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByRef pvarIn As Variant, ByVal pstrFormat As Long, ByRef pbTokCur As Any, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef pbstrOut As Long, ByVal lcid As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If

Private Const S_OK As Long = 0
Private Const E_INVALIDARG As Long = &H80070057
Private Const E_OUTOFMEMORY As Long = &H8007000E
Private Const DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL As Long = &H80020013
Private Const DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH As Long = &H80020005


Public Function FormatForLocale(ByVal Expression As Variant, Optional ByVal Format As String, Optional ByVal FirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, Optional ByVal FirstWeekOfYear As VbFirstWeekOfYear = vbUseSystem, Optional ByVal PatternLocaleID As Long = 0, Optional ByVal TargetLocaleID As Long = 0) As String
  Dim b() As Byte, t As Long
  Dim hResult As Long
  #If VBA7 Then
  Dim pBstrResult As LongPtr
  #Else
  Dim pBstrResult As Long
  #End If
  Dim res As String

  Const CHUNK_SIZE As Long = 256


  If TypeOf Expression Is Excel.Range Then
    Expression = Expression.Value
  End If


  ReDim b(1 To CHUNK_SIZE)

  Do
    hResult = VarTokenizeFormatString(StrPtr(Format), b(LBound(b)), UBound(b) - LBound(b) + 1, FirstDayOfWeek, FirstWeekOfYear, PatternLocaleID, t)

    Select Case hResult
    Case S_OK
      Exit Do
    Case E_INVALIDARG
      Err.Raise 5, , "Some arguments are invalid."
    Case DISP_E_BUFFERTOOSMALL
      ReDim b(LBound(b) To UBound(b) + CHUNK_SIZE)
    Case Else
      Err.Raise 5, , "Internal error. Unexpected error code returned from system."
    End Select
  Loop

  Select Case VarFormatFromTokens(Expression, StrPtr(Format), b(LBound(b)), 0, pBstrResult, TargetLocaleID)
  Case S_OK
    CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(res), pBstrResult, Len(pBstrResult)
  Case E_OUTOFMEMORY
    Err.Raise 7
  Case E_INVALIDARG
    Err.Raise 5, , "Some arguments are invalid."
  Case DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH
    Err.Raise 5, , "The argument could not be coerced to the specified type."
  Case Else
    Err.Raise 5, , "Internal error. Unexpected error code returned from system."
  End Select

  FormatForLocale = res
End Function
```

Now you have a function, `FormatForLocale`, that mimics the default VBA `Format` function, but adds two additional parameters. To get the result you want, you can do:

```vb
result = FormatForLocale(123456789, "#,###.0##", , , LOCALE_INVARIANT, LOCALE_GERMAN)
```

where `LOCALE_INVARIANT` and `LOCALE_GERMAN` are constants you can look up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can call it from a worksheet as well:

```vb
=FormatForLocale(123456789,"#,###.0##",,,127,3079)
```

Comment: I think that the correct format string would actually be `#,###.0##` because the `,` represents the culture-specific thousands separator and the `.` represents the culture-specific decimal separator.  When you open the worksheet on a computer with (for example) French localization settings, the resulting number will look like "1.234,567"

Comment: @phoog It depends on how you set the format. If you are using the interface, then it completely depends on the current locale (for instance, with Russian locale you have to set it to `# ###,0#`). If you are setting format from code, then you are correct, `#,###.0#` is the thing. I'll add that.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'd like it to be culture independent and use it in the Text() function. Using the format "#.###,0##" I get "12237119.867,761" - there are still two dots missing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Cosmo `Text` function in Excel is locale-dependent. You can't do anything about it I'm afraid. If you're going to use `Text`, you have to either choose a fixed locale under which it will work, or create a lookup table for every existing locale (or a translating function). As for the missing dot, that is probably because you have this type of digit grouping set in control panel: `123456 789`.

Comment: @GSerg Do you know any alternative way? I don't have to use the Text() function, but the result should be locale independent.

Comment: @Cosmo You could try to write your own locale-independent formatter using [`VarTokenizeFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221340.aspx) and [`VarFormatFromTokens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221147.aspx). I don't have time at the moment, but in the evening I'll try to post a working sample.

Comment: Thank you very much @GSerg! This works great! I just have one small problem with it. If I call it with an explicit value "=FormatForLocale(123456789,"#,###.0##";;;127,3079)" everything works fine, however if the value is in another cell (reference), I get a argument exception "=FormatForLocale(A2,"#,###.0##";;;127,3079)". Do you know why?

Comment: @Cosmo Cannot reproduce, works for me. Try declaring the first argument as `ByVal Expression As Variant`. If that doesn't work, see what's special about that value in `A2`.

Comment: @GSerg, adding ByVal doesn't help :/ Using the debugger I see that the problem is in the statement: "Select Case VarFormatFromTokens(Expression, StrPtr(Format), b(LBound(b)), 0, pBstrResult, TargetLocaleID)". It raises the case "Err.Raise 5, , Internal error. Unexpected error code returned from system." If I provide the value explicit, the pBstrResult is not equal 0, however in my case it is 0 (using a referenced cell). I don't know why...

Comment: @Cosmo Can you prepare an excel workbook that minimally shows the error (just a few filled cells) and upload it somewhere? I can't seem to reproduce this error. Besides, "case else" should not really happen, the function is documented to return only those error codes.

Comment: @GSerg, thank you. I've uploaded it for you: http://www.mediafire.com/?4h7f6gwa1159xm9

Comment: @Cosmo All that is very strange. I'm not sure why it happens, but everything works fine on my PC (Windows 7 Home Basic + Office 2003 Pro, Russian locale), but fails on my office PC in the way you describe (Windows 7 Pro + Office 2003 Pro English-UK). This is spooky and I can't explain why it is so. The error happens when `Epression` is of type `Excel.Range`. The actual `Excel.Range` gets passed to the formatting function, and it fails. Whereas on my PC, the value of the range is passed, and all works fine. Or maybe it's about permissions. Anyway, see the edit.

Comment: I have credited your excellent code in a blog post I've written.  I have written the inverse function which takes foreign language date strings and gives date, much easier.  https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2020/10/internationalise-dates-in-vba.html