# Excel Macro VBA: Add minutes and hours together where total can exceed 24 hours

Tags: vba, date, time

hopefully this is a silly question with an easy answer.

I have no choice really what language I use, which is why I'm doing this in Excel with VBA.

I'm basically calculating total downtime hours over a month. I need to add small amounts of minutes together to find out a total that will be over 24 hours of course.

Here is the scenario:

Server A was down for 3 hours and 52 minutes this month.
Server B was down for 15 hours and 25 minutes this month.

Server B had 7 hours and 23 minutes downtime during a critical period, so this is multplied by 3 to equate it to non-critical downtime.

Server A has: 3 hours 52 minutes at x1
Server B has: 8 hours 2 minutes at x1
Server B has: 7 hours 21 minutes at x3

All downtimes and restoration times are manually listed in a sheet in time formats recognised by excel, eg:

event 1  :  19/11/2017 5:00  :  19/11/2017 14:12
event 2  :  13/11/2017 6:00  :  13/11/2017 6:40
event 3  :  13/11/2017 7:57  :  13/11/2017 9:01
event 4  :  17/11/2017 6:15  :  18/11/2017 8:10

Weekends are not counted

Only minutes between 6am and 6pm are counted

Minutes increase in priority during certain time periods:

06:00-07:00, 07:00-09:00, 09:00-10:00, 10:00-14:00

High priority minutes are multiplied to equate peak time usage with lower standard time usage

I'm struggling to find a way to add times together to count hours, excel trys to give answers relative to 01/01/1900 or some "real" date.

I'm going the opposite way, I have the real dates, I need to work with the hours between them. Is there a data format that is in plain hours:minutes?

I thought it was obvious but I'll state clearly in case, start time and end times are not necessarily on the same day. They can be any time, any relationship, sometimes start time will be *after* the end time due to how faults are reported. Obviously that counts as 0 minutes in that case.

---

My current methodology for attacking this problem is:

1. increase the start time until it becomes valid charge time
2. calculate the minutes until there is a change such as end of day or higher priority time slot, or start time = end time
3. add the calculated minutes to a total
4. increase the start time by the calculated minutes
5. start cycle again from the the new 'start time' and loop until there are no minutes remaining between start time and end time

   ```
   startof:

   'move to start of next chargeable day, if not on a chargeable day
   'eg weekends, public holidays, easy function to write
   Do While testForChargeable() = False

       opnDate = DateAdd("d", 1, opnDate)
       opnTime = "06:00"

   Loop

   'check if open time is past the end of chargeable time, 18:00
   If (opnTime >= endofdayTime) Then
       'move to start of next chargeable day
       opnDate = DateAdd("d", 1, opnDate)
       opnTime = "06:00"
   End If

   'check if open time is after close time and fault is excluded
   If (opnDate >= bisDate) And (opnTime >= bisTime) Then
       GoTo last
   End If

   'check if close time is on same day as start time
   If DateDiff("d", opnDate, bisDate) = 0 Then
       'if it is, add minutes between opntime and bistime
       chargeTime = chargeTime + calculateChargeTime(opnTime, bisTime)
       'calculation ends, loop naturally terminates
   Else
       'if not, add remaining mintes of day to chargeable time
       chargeTime = chargeTime + calculateChargeTime(opnTime, endofdayTime)
       'move to start of next day
       opnDate = DateAdd("d", 1, opnDate)
       opnTime = "06:00"
       GoTo startof
   End If

   last:
   ```

Cheers

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: The easy (or silly?) answer is obviously "sometimes" (or is that "some times"?)

Comment: I hit enter when adding tags and accidentally submitted the question before I'd written it

Comment: Change **NumberFormat** to something like `[hh]:mm`, this forces the Sum to be in hours as max unit.

Comment: Patrick that sounds great, but I can't see how to do this in VBA, like I can with the cell properties

Comment: @averagescripter In VBA you would use `someRangeReference.NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm"`.  So calculate your total number of days (e.g. `1.26`, stick that in your output cell, and format that cell - it will then display as `30:14`.)

Comment: So, in your example, if you calculated 3hrs 52mins (which Excel would treat as 0.161111), 8hrs 2mins (0.334722) and 7hrs 21mins (0.30625) then you just have to take the first number + second number + 3 * third number to get 1.414583, which formatted as "[hh]:mm" displays as `33:57`.

Comment: It would be better to show the actual code you are using - it probably only requires a minor tweak, and it's much easier to make that small change to your code rather than guessing how to best describe the change in English.

Comment: And don't work in minutes, just work in days - it saves having to multiply date differences by 1440 to get minutes and then dividing the answers you get by 1440 so that they can be displayed as times.

Comment: I have to work in minutes, I added more detail above so hopefully the problem is clearer. I have to calculate one bite at a time because every minute is not equal, some minutes during the day are higher priority than others

Comment: But a minute is 1/1440th of a day, and it is just as valid to say some 1/1440ths of a day have a higher priority than others as it is to say some minutes have a higher priority.  It's just a waste of time to multiply a number by 1440 and then divide it by 1440 later.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>**Edit:** *Now that we're on the same page and I have what I think is a workable solution for you, I'll replace my previous answer [re: How Excel dates are related to value (ie., 1 day = 1)] with this one.  The previous answer (and my computer messing up while trying to post it) is viewable in the Edit History.*</sub>

---

So, you need a way to count minutes duration, between two DateTimes, and include or exclude sub-time-ranges based on criteria that might require ongoing adjustment, and you want this in a VBA function for use in automation of downtime data analysis.

**Try this:**

```
Option Explicit

Function MinsBetween(startDateTime As Date, stopDateTime As Date, count_StartTime As Date, count_StopTime As Date) As Long

    Dim startTime As Date, stopTime As Date 

    'ignore dates, use only the times
    startTime = startDateTime - Int(startDateTime)
    stopTime = stopDateTime - Int(stopDateTime)

    If startTime >= count_StopTime Or stopTime <= count_StartTime Then
        'entire period falls outside of times to count
        MinsBetween = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    'make 'adj' times start/end at counted times if necessary
    startDateTime = IIf(startTime < count_StartTime, count_StartTime, startTime)
    stopDateTime = IIf(stopTime > count_StopTime, count_StopTime, stopTime)

    'calculate & return minutes between (never return negative number)
    MinsBetween = Abs(DateDiff("n", startDateTime, stopDateTime))

End Function
```

This function counts only the minutes between `startDateTime` and `stopDateTime` that also fall between `count_StartTime` and `count_StopTime`.

**Expects**:
 - `count_StartTime` & `count_StopTime` to be an Excel Time (or number between 0 and 1)
 - `startDateTime` & `stopDateTime` to be an Excel Time *or* DateTime.

**Returns** a long integer.  Could be referenced in VBA or as a worksheet function.

**Example usage:**

> The outage 'event' occurred from 05:00 to 07:03 on 2017/11/19, but only the times between 6am and 6pm should be counted:

```
Debug.Print MinsBetween("2017/11/19 05:00", "2017/11/19 07:03", "06:00", "18:00")
```

> The outage 'event' occurred from 05:00 to 14:12 on 2017/11/19.  The duration that occurred between [peak period] 1pm to 2pm are have higher priority and should be counted as "*double-time*":

```
Debug.Print (2 * MinsBetween("2017/11/19 05:00", "2017/11/19 14:12", "13:00", "15:00") )
```

As weekends are ignored entirely, those reports could be excluded with a simple check like this:

```
Function isWeekend(wDateTime As Date) As Boolean
    isWeekend = Weekday(DateValue(wDateTime)) = vbSaturday Or Weekday(DateValue(wDateTime)) = vbSunday
End Function
```

...returns `TRUE` if the supplied date (or datetime) falls on a weekend, otherwise returns FALSE.

---

You could use a combination of these functions to build sub or worksheet function around your custom criteria and adjust as needed.

**For example:**

```
Function DownTimeMinutes(startDateTime As Date, stopDateTime As Date) As Long
'you could process your custom criteria for each start/stop period here

    Dim dtMinutes As Long

    'for example:

    'IGNORE DOWNTIME ON WEEKENDS
    If isWeekend(startDateTime) Then
        'ignore weekeends
        DownTimeMinutes = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    'COUNT MINUTES BETWEEN 6AM-6PM with "x1" multiplier
    dtMinutes = MinsBetween(startDateTime, stopDateTime, "06:00", "18:00")

    'DON'T COUNT LUNCH BREAK (or something like that)
    '(subtract these minutes from total)
    dtMinutes = dtMinutes - MinsBetween(startDateTime, stopDateTime, "12:00", "12:30")

    'COUNT MINUTES BETWEEN 14:00-15:00 as "x3"
    '(already counted as "x1" so add "2x these minutes"
    dtMinutes = dtMinutes + (2 * MinsBetween(startDateTime, stopDateTime, "14:00", "15:00"))

    'return adjusted minutes for this downtime event
    DownTimeMinutes = dtMinutes

End Function
```

---

*Side note:* This is the short-story of the long-example I was getting at when I thought part of your issue was trouble converting varying M/D/Y , MM/DD/YY , M-DD-YYYY , etc, manual entries to DateTimes that Excel would recognize regardless of the user's Regional date settings.

As I understand it, you don't need it now but I figured I might as well add it to my answer anyway :

```
=DATE(MID(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))-FIND("/",LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))),FIND("/",RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))-FIND("/",LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))))+1,4),LEFT(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))-FIND("/",LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))),FIND("/",RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))-FIND("/",LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))))-1),FIND("/",RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))-FIND("/",LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))))))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))
```

Generally I don't condone the use of gigantic formulas (I was more concerned about getting it into a single function that about readability), and there are other ways to deal with date issues caused by Regional differences in shared workbooks (including [Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542249/8112776)) but in most cases I find text manipulation will do the job too.

Comment: Thanks, I get that, but I can't use that method.
In my case, I have to find out the difference in minutes between the down and restore time, and add downtime_minutes x 3 if the downtime happens to occur during a specific time period during the day.

Comment: I assume with, for example, `event 4 : 17/11/2017 6:15 : 18/11/2017 8:10` the first value is the down time and second value is the restore time, so this one was down for almost **26 hours**, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example, I have hundreds of these lines in a sheet, hence needing to write a macro to avoid hand calculation which is currently the only method we have.
There are other details as well, this is a simplified version of the real thing which has lots of factors that contribute to the end result, but the essentials are described in the question

Comment: Even more significantly though, 26 hours crosses over all different time periods where minutes down are not counted (overnight), or they are counted double or triple due to higher priority time.

Comment: absolutely, I'm putting together a thorough answer in return for your patience (and afterwards headed to SuperUser to ask for help with my dang laptop, hence the partial posts!)   The amount of data isn't as important as the format.  Are all the date/time's in the same format as you posted?

Comment: They are manually entered, it's hard to enforce but will always be something recognised as a date by Excel. Eg  11/12/2017 14:32   or   02:00 PM 11/12/2017   or some variaton of those. I'm writing another part that will validate correctly formatted dates

Comment: Oh! They are currently something always recognized as dates, perfect. This is highly depended on regional settings.  For example, my Windows "Short Date" regional setting is YYYY-MM-DD and therefore my Excel won't automatically recognize your example "17/11/2017" without manipulating the text into separate parts (year, month, day, time).

Comment: so therefore could you test with your example data, enter `17/11/2017 6:15` into A1, enter `18/11/2017 8:10` into A2, and in A3, enter formula: `=(A2-A1)*24*60`  You should get a number of minutes.  If it is formatted as a date, right click the cell, Format Cells, Number tab, and choose a **Number** format.  If that still doesn't display a number of minutes then Excel may _not_ be recognizing the values as date... _yet_

Comment: If you'd like to expedite this for both of us, you can send me a worksheet with some actual data, at least a page of varying date entries, and I'll slap in some formulas (and possibly a VBA function), send it back, and it will be easier to explain afterwards.  (Normally we don't do this but I see that you're motivated to get the basics and take over, as opposed to wanting someone else to do your work for you,)

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm purposely staying away from any kind of manual cell entry. I'm writing this for a colleague who needs to be able to click "Run Macro" and then get the answers. This isn't a one off problem either, it takes up huge man hours every month calculating the down time for hundreds of units, long story short I bet the boss I could write a macro to do it and here we are. I can send you some sanitised sample data and my current messy source

Comment: No cell entry is required, it's easier to manipulate strings and dates in VBA anyway!  If you're confident that _Excel will recognize the date_ then I can move to the _"which minutes to count"_ part.  I'm kind of a data geek (ie, do it for fun, lol) and I've worked with date/time comparisons to specific sets of rules lots in the past.  (Actually currently have a project for a transit company involving similar logic).  It's doesn't have to be your real data, but making sample data that will pass **and** fail each of the rules, for testing purposes, is sometimes more of a pain than the solution.

Comment: I would need a bit of clarification on the rules too...  `Weekends are not counted`, simple; `Only minutes between 6am and 6pm are counted`, okay, **but** `Minutes 3X in priority during certain time periods:06:00-07:00, 07:00-09:00, 09:00-10:00, 10:00-14:00`, that's **all** of 06:00-14:00 that they are 3X?  Or if each period different multiplier?

Comment: I actually don't have the exact details, I code so that down the track I can add and subtract different priority time periods as SLA changes.
The example you quoted was just showing different time periods across the day, as an example, and each would be weighted differently. 7am to 9am would be worth more than 6am to 7am for reasons.

Comment: @averagescripter all good, I don't need your sample data anymore; I posted a new answer (replacing my previous answer[s]; if needed, you can view them in the edit history.  Hope that works for you, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and all your hard work helping me out.
After reading through the code, it looks like this will only work if start and end times are on the same day... but very often in reality something will go wrong before midnight and be resolved after midnight, or go down on Friday and be back up on Tuesday. I added the code I've written that basically eats the time section by section from start to finish. It doesn't work perfectly due to data types, but I'll try with integerising like with yours