# How Do I Format a Label to Display 12 Hour Time Format Without the AM/PM in VB6?

Tags: time, vb6, format

I am creating a clock program using Visual Basic 6 that is using a timer to show the time in a label on my main form and I have an options form on which users can customize several settings, including changing the time format between 12 Hour and 24 Hour format.  If 12 hour format is choosen, I would also like to allow a person to toggle the display of the AM/PM.  There is no option (from what I can find) for 12 hour time without the morning/afternoon marker in the documentation  My question, therefore, is this: how do I display the time in 12 hour format without the AM and PM?  All is working except this.
Please reference the code from my options form below and the Public variable declarations below.

Variable Declarations in Module

```
Public strTimeFormat As String, strDateFormat As String

Public Const strSecond = "ss"
Public Const strAMPM = "AMPM"
Public Const strColon = ":"

Public strCustom As String, strHourCurrentSelection As String, strMinuteCurrentSelection As String, strTimeCurrentSelection As String
```

Options Form (`frmOptions`)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub chkAMPM_Click()
If chkAMPM.Value = True Then
strTimeCurrentSelection = strHourCurrentSelection + strColon + strMinuteCurrentSelection + strAMPM
End If

End Sub

Private Sub chkSeconds_Click()
If chkSeconds.Value = True Then
strTimeCurrentSelection = strHourCurrentSelection + strColon + strMinuteCurrentSelection + strSecond
Else
strTimeCurrentSelection = strHourCurrentSelection + strColon + strMinuteCurrentSelection
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdApply_Click()
strTimeFormat = strTimeCurrentSelection
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
MsgBox "Place code here to set options and close dialog!"
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
'handle ctrl+tab to move to the next tab
If Shift = vbCtrlMask And KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
    i = tbsOptions.SelectedItem.Index
    If i = tbsOptions.Tabs.Count Then
        'last tab so we need to wrap to tab 1
        Set tbsOptions.SelectedItem = tbsOptions.Tabs(1)
    Else
        'increment the tab
        Set tbsOptions.SelectedItem = tbsOptions.Tabs(i + 1)
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
'center the form
Me.Move (Screen.Width - Me.Width) / 2, (Screen.Height - Me.Height) / 
End Sub

Private Sub opt12Hour_Click()
opt24NoZero.Enabled = False
opt24Zero.Enabled = False
chkColon.Enabled = False

txtCustomTimeLayout.Enabled = False
txtCustomTimeLayout.BackColor = &H8000000F

opt12NoZero.Enabled = True
opt12Zero.Enabled = True
chkAMPM.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub opt12NoZero_Click()
strHourCurrentSelection = ""
strMinuteCurrentSelection = ""

strHourCurrentSelection = "h"
strMinuteCurrentSelection = "mm"

strTimeCurrentSelection = strHourCurrentSelection + strColon + strMinuteCurrentSelection
End Sub

Private Sub opt12Zero_Click()
strHourCurrentSelection = ""
strMinuteCurrentSelection = ""

strHourCurrentSelection = "hh"
strMinuteCurrentSelection = "mm"

strTimeCurrentSelection = strHourCurrentSelection + strColon + strMinuteCurrentSelection

End Sub

Private Sub opt24Hour_Click()
opt12NoZero.Enabled = False
opt12Zero.Enabled = False
chkAMPM.Enabled = False

txtCustomTimeLayout.Enabled = False
txtCustomTimeLayout.BackColor = &H8000000F

opt24NoZero.Enabled = True
opt24Zero.Enabled = True
chkColon.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub opt24NoZero_Click()
strHourCurrentSelection = ""
strMinuteCurrentSelection = ""

strHourCurrentSelection = "H"
strMinuteCurrentSelection = "mm"

strTimeCurrentSelection = strHourCurrentSelection + strColon + strMinuteCurrentSelection
End Sub

Private Sub opt24Zero_Click()
strHourCurrentSelection = ""
strMinuteCurrentSelection = ""

strHourCurrentSelection = "HH"
strMinuteCurrentSelection = "mm"

strTimeCurrentSelection = strHourCurrentSelection + strColon + strMinuteCurrentSelection

End Sub

Private Sub optCustomTime_Click()
opt12NoZero.Enabled = False
opt12Zero.Enabled = False
chkAMPM.Enabled = False

opt24NoZero.Enabled = False
opt24Zero.Enabled = False
chkColon.Enabled = False

txtCustomTimeLayout.Enabled = True
txtCustomTimeLayout.BackColor = &H80000009

End Sub

Private Sub tbsOptions_Click()

Dim i As Integer
'show and enable the selected tab's controls
'and hide and disable all others
For i = 0 To tbsOptions.Tabs.Count - 1
    If i = tbsOptions.SelectedItem.Index - 1 Then
        picOptions(i).Left = 210
        picOptions(i).Enabled = True
    Else
        picOptions(i).Left = -20000
        picOptions(i).Enabled = False
    End If
Next

End Sub

Private Sub txtCustomTimeLayout_Change()
strTimeCurrentSelection = txtCustomTimeLayout.Text
End Sub
```

Public Subs Module

```
Public Sub Clock()
frmClock.lblTime.Caption = Format(Now, strTimeFormat)
frmClock.lblDate.Caption = Format(Now, strDateFormat)

End Sub
```

Timer_Click() Event

```
Private Sub tmrClock_Timer()
Clock

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple approach:

```
Left$(Format$(Now(), "Hh:NnA/P"), 5)
```

Comment: This will work, but it goes against the code structure where the final function just uses the format string that was built according to many conditions. Now the final function will need to understand these conditions as well, in order to figure if it also needs to `Left` the formatting result, and if so, for how many characters (because leading zeroes can be on or off, according to user selection, and when they are off, the hours/minutes can take either one or two places).

Comment: Which can be mitigated by using `Len(result) - 1` instead of the `5`, and by setting or clearing the flag (e.g. `blnDoLeft`) from the event handlers that control AM/PM user selection.

Answer (score 1):

The `AMPM` formatting token [respects the current locale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx).
It does unconditionally sets the 12-hour mode for the time pieces, but it outputs "AM/PM" only when your locale says so.

For instance, under my locale, where the 24 hour format is the default, `Format$(Now, "h:m:s AMPM")` will format the time according to 12-hours rules, but will not print "AM" or "PM".

There is a different flavour of the `AMPM` token: `AM/PM`. That one always prints AM or PM, even when your locale does not want it.

It is therefore easy to make sure AM/PM is always printed: you simply need to use `Const strAMPM = "AM/PM"` instead of `Const strAMPM = "AMPM"`.

However making sure the AM/PM is suppressed under all locales is a different matter: you can't do that with formatting strings alone. You do need to put `AMPM` into the formatting string to switch it to the 12-hour mode, but if you do, AM or PM will appear in the output if your locale says so.

Therefore, you need to make the `Format` function use a different locale. I have written a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523219/11683) that does this.

Pick two locale IDs that have the behaviours you want (one showing AM/PM, one suppressing it).
E.g.

```
FormatForLocale(Now, "h:m:s ampm", TargetLocaleID:=&H0C09)
```

will print AM or PM, and e.g.

```
FormatForLocale(Now, "h:m:s ampm", TargetLocaleID:=&H0419)
```

will not.

You would store the `TargetLocaleID` value in the same way you store the other bits of the formatting string, and change it to one or another value when the user selects or cancels AM/PM.

---

While you can use the function as is, in your particular case where you build and store the formatting string, you might take the bit that calls `VarTokenizeFormatString` and stores the result out of the function and make a separate function that only handles tokenization and stores the result in a byte array. Then you would store the byte array instead of the final formatting string, which would save you recalculating it each time you call `VarFormatFromTokens`.