# How to apply conditional formatting where comma is the decimal separator

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Code to apply a conditional format. When range.value is lower than 7,2 it stays white, when higher than 8,1 it turns red.
This code runs on my laptop. On another computer, it throws this error.

> Run-time error '5':
> Invalid procedure call or argument

```vb
Private Sub totalEPS(mySelection As Range)
    With mySelection.FormatConditions
        .Delete
        With .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=7,2")
            .Interior.Color = 65535
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        With .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=8,1")
            .Interior.Color = 255
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Debug on the other computer stops in the line

`With .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=7,2")`

Comment: Pretty sure that's Excel 2019, given Win32 Excel is on a 3-year release schedule. Or is it 365?

Comment: Verify your respective regional settings match. Looks like you're using `,` for a decimal separator, and your colleague would be using a `.` dot? Try replacing `Formula1:="=7,2"` with `Formula1:="=7" & Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) & "2"` (and same with the `,` in `8,1`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it has to do with the decimal separator - that comma would be a dot on an en-US operating system.

Try adding this function to your module:

```
Public Function LocalizeDecimal(ByVal value As Double) As String
    LocalizeDecimal = Replace(Str(value), ".", Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator))
End Function
```

Then edit the `Formula1` argument to something like this:

```
With .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=" & LocalizeDecimal(7.2))
```

And:

```
With .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=" & LocalizeDecimal(8.1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, by pure chance I came accross the answer in this post, when trying to debug a separate piece of code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652409/using-vba-to-detect-which-decimal-sign-the-computer-is-using
but you were able to hit the nail on the head so to speak

Comment: I don't see how that could work, as `CStr` specifically uses the current locale, and therefore has no guarantee to produce a `.` - and when it does, replacing it with the current decimal separator should be a no-op because it's going to be the `.`. `Str`, on the other hand, always uses the `.`. On a side note, there is a [more flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523219/11683) approach ;)

Comment: @GSerg thanks, edited! If I recall, the OP was happy with just the comment and I provided the (untested air-code, apparently) answer for the sake of closure.