# Can we get custom number format from user and apply that to columns in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, user-input, number-formatting

Hope you all are well.
I am struggling with a task which requires me to get an input from the user which will specify what number format the user want (currency symbol and the separator to be used). And then save this setting in the windows registry and apply this number format to columns. One of the issues is the European number format in which the separator is . and the decimal point is , for example an amount in USD 1,000.55 will be equivalent to 1.000,55 in European format.

Can someone please help and share your thought on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `And then save this setting in the windows registry` - no, you should [never do that](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873).

Comment: @GSerg thats fine, I can save the user setting in an external file so that it can be used for different sessions. What do you think about the other issue?

Comment: C.f. function `LocalizeDecimal()` at [(Conditional) formatting working code ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994084/vba-conditional-formatting-working-code-in-excel-2003-does-not-work-in-excel/59994588#59994588)

Comment: You can use [GetSetting()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getsetting-function) and
[SaveSetting()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/savesetting-statement).  What is the reason that you want to save it to the registry?

Comment: Aside from storing the format (doesn't really matter how you do that) what is the specific problem you're facing?  Can you list an example sequence of events which you think would give you problems?

Comment: I need something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523219/12130626) by @GSerg, but how do I make the 32 bit DLL run on 64bit?

Comment: @NTR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword?

Comment: I have updated https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523219/11683 for `PtrSafe`.

Comment: Apologies I am not that advanced in VBA so earlier when I tried PtrSafe it gave me type mismatch error, but now it worked. Thank you @GSerg. I believe we wont be able to get the function output as number without tweaking the windows local settings, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The function specifically exists so that you could output a number in any locale without tweaking anything anywhere.