# Difficulty forcing VBA to parse dates in US/UK format

Tags: vba, date, datetime, locale

Thanks to all those who have helped thus far and helped me refine the problem

I'm receiving a CSV file from a third party software application with date time stamp in UK format that can be read by the VBA as a US date format

My machines "Region and Language Settings" are set to English (United Kingdom) but if I use
`Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)`
The result is 1033 - ie: English, US and not fitting my machine settings.

CSV is a file with columns as follows:

`| report name | value | % | date |`

CSV created by a program and saved by users - a direct save of the CSV to disk by the third party app results in CSV table rows as follows:
"Report name","264","2.2 %","08 Jul 2021 11:05" (this imports correctly)

If users open the CSV and then save from Excel the file is saved as follows (note no quotation marks and amended date format:
Report name,1,0.00%,01/07/2021 12:37 (this fails to import correctly - cell read by VBA as 7th Jan 21)

My code should be able to handle both situations.

I'm importing the CSV data as follows:

```
    Set csvWB = Workbooks.Open(my_FileName)
    Set csvData = csvWB.Worksheets(1)
    Dim csvReportAr() As Variant 'array of reprot names from column one of the CSV
    Dim csvNumberAr() As Variant 'array of values (report results) from col 2 of the CSV
    Dim csvDateAr() As Date 'array of the dates the reports were run
    
    Do While csvData.Cells(cellRow, 1).Value <> Empty
      Do While csvData.Cells(cellRow, 1).Value <> Empty
      ReDim Preserve csvReportAr(cellRow)
      ReDim Preserve csvNumberAr(cellRow)
      ReDim Preserve csvDateAr(cellRow)
    
      csvReportAr(cellRow - 1) = csvData.Cells(cellRow, 1).Value
      csvNumberAr(cellRow - 1) = csvData.Cells(cellRow, 2).Value
        
      Debug.Print "cell value = " & csvData.Cells(cellRow, 4).Value
      Debug.Print "Month (of cell value) = " & Month(csvDateAr(cellRow - 1))
    
      csvDateAr(cellRow - 1) = convertDateUKtoUS(csvData.Cells(cellRow, 4).Value)
      Debug.Print "Date value = " & csvDateAr(cellRow - 1)
      Debug.Print "Month of date = " & Month(csvDateAr(cellRow - 1))
      cellRow = cellRow + 1
    Loop
```

the debug statements print the following:

```
cell value = 07/01/2021 06:45:00
Month (of cell value) = 12
Date value = 07/01/2021
```

The difficulty is that the date I'm trying to import here is listed as 01/07/2021 06:45:00 in the CSV (1st July) based on the text editor view of the CSV.  Just reading this cell value it seems that the VBA assumes this is a date and stores as a date saved in US format.

I suspect this is a locale issue?  My locale settings seem incongruous and other users might have erroneous locale settings as well so we should be able to account for this

Questions:

- Can I force VBA to read the date-time stamp as a string and then parse manually to ensure read as date in UK format? - OR - Can I read as a date time stamp specifying a specific format to read with?
- Can you advise on the issue with locale with VBA stating locale is English US whilst machine settings seem to be English UK?
- Can I change the locale with VBA temporarily? (other posts I've read suggests this is not advised!)
- Is my use of cell.value inappropriate?

Rest of post deleted as probably no longer relevant

Thanks to all contributors so far!

Comment: not the problem but `str = split(split(dateString," ")(0),"/")` will return an array of strings then you would do: `Day = str(0)`,`Month =str(1)`, and `Year=str(2)` But I would also not use Day,Month,Year as variables as they mean something in vba.

Comment: and just so you are aware, this can be done with formula if one has Office 365: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581292/convert-from-us-to-uk-format

Comment: If what ever your system sees as a month is over 12 then it is imported as a string.  If it is less there is a strong possibility that it is imported as a date with the month and days flipped.  It would be better if you parsed the date through a text editor or using a language that can read the data without conversion before opening in excel or get the provider to use a universal date format like `yyyy-mm-dd` which will convert correctly whether in the US or the UK.

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Comment: It's not clear why/when you use `convertDateUKtoUS` - if the CSV has UK-formatted dates and your locale is set to UK then there should be no problems with dates opening the CSV in Excel?  Are you not doing that but doing something else?  Seems though that from your testing you need to use `DateSerial` and not `CDate`.

Comment: If you have a date `dt` then `Debug.Print Format(dt,"yyyy-mm-dd")` should be consistent regardless of locale.

Comment: _this only happens on some CSV files and not others_ ... then those CSV files hold different formats and must be handled accordingly. Date handling in VBA is not "random" by any measure. Also, string handling of dates should be avoided if at all possible; indeed, using localised month abbreviations. You haven't revealed your (sample) data, but you may get some ideas how to convert these in the `DateText` module found at [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

Comment: `I understand it is not possible to force CDate to read a date in a set format?` - it is. It uses your current Windows locale. `I understand I cannot force VBA to use a certain locale in interpreting dates?` - not without some work first. You can make it [format for specific locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523219/11683) with `VarFormatFromTokens`, just in the same way you can make it parse dates using a specific locale with [`VarDateFromStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-vardatefromstr).

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner your split string function is far more elegant than mine - as a side note though I have set as "Option base 1" but with split string functionality as it described I need to use arrayLoc(0) - arrayLoc(2) - seems odd to me but it works!

Comment: @norie great question.  I think you may have hit the nail on the head but I'm still stuck.  I'll explain the steps above and tweak the original post (sorry new here and carriage return posted this before ready!)

Comment: @JamesBoorer When the CSV file is initially opened are the dates incorrect?

Comment: @norie If I open the CSV the dates are UK format and perfect.  In the open "spreadsheet" of the CSV I've added additional dates in various formats like 7th Jan 2021 and 1st July 2021 and looked at the integer /floating values for these and they are OK - by that I mean 1st July 21 value == the 1/7/21 date in the CSV I'm trying to import.  Similarly a file with date 6/7/21 6th July 21 imports as 7th June but another CSV 8/7/21 imports as 8th July correctly.

Comment: If the dates are fine when you open the file what's the purpose of the posted code?

Comment: @norie I'm assuming that excel files /CSV files have a locale set - if I understand correctly the locale is set by the machine and dates interpreted in context of the machine locale?  Alternatively could there be an issue where some CSV dates are imported as dates and some as strings???

Comment: @JamesBoorer Have you considered the code could be the problem? VBA can do funny things with dates when you read/write them from arrays.

Comment: There is a huge difference between reading the CSV yourself with cdate, like you initially made it look like, and letting Excel open it and then process the cells, like what you have revealed you are actually doing. It's too late after Excel has corrupted the data. Open it with [OpenText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) and describe your fields properly in `FieldInfo`.

Comment: @GSerg very useful comment - has advanced my understanding of the problem (post updated with text held in the CSVs).  I still can't get VBA to read the datetime stamp in UK format and wonder if its a locale issue

Comment: @norie - its definitely my code that's wrong! There must be a way around this but its not clear to me at the moment.  The originally code posted was where I was trying to swap days and moths from the incorrectly read CSV but your and other comments helped me realise the problem was further up in the program and the actual reading of the CSV is where it was failing and the error carried through.

Answer (score 1):

I have partial but inelegant solution - I hope others can do better than me. I still can't work out why the UK date is being parsed to a US date automatically.

Thanks to all for their help as I could not have got my project to work without your helpful comments.

My partial solution:
Read the data from the CSV, assuming it may have been parsed incorrectly

If day(importDate) <=12 we are at risk of erroneous date import

create an alternate date with transposed days /months from the importDate

Use a vbYesNo MsgBox to get user to confirm which date is correct.

---

This works for my project as all dates in the single CSV file should be equal, You could use a similar solution of error checking a date for being read in US vs UK format  if all dates in your CSV where recorded in the same format.  However it will not help others who want to processes multiple CSVs or who may have a CSV with different date formats in it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to read the csv file into an array using a CSV parser that lets you specify the file's date format, and then paste the array into a worksheet.

Here's such a parser (I'm the author):

https://github.com/PGS62/VBA-CSV

In this example, `Data` is pasted to a new worksheet.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim Target As Range

    Data = CSVRead("c:\temp\datesukformat.csv", _
        ConvertTypes:=True, _
        Delimiter:=",", _
        DateFormat:="D/M/Y")

    Set Target = Application.Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2))

    Target.value = Data

End Sub
```